# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta MAX(id) en Python con pymsql?

Tags: mysql, python

Quiero obtener el máximo `id` de una tabla para luego almacenarla en una variable, pero no se qué va mal en el código, he buscado en internet y no encuentro solución.
Ejecuto la misma sentencia workbench y funciona normal, debería reconocerme el id "3" (cosa que sí ocurre en workbench), pero al ejecutarlo en Python me regresa "1", como si solo leyera el primer id.

Código en Python:

```html
connection = pymysql.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password="",
db="database"
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
maxid="SELECT MAX(id) FROM columna"
cursor.execute(maxid)
```

Regresa:

> 1

En el workbnech solo escribo el siguiente query y sí funciona:

```html
SELECT MAX(id) FROM columna
```

Regresa:

> 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` puede retorna un iterador, o el número de filas afectadas, no los datos en sí (ver la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) y ver también [este enlace](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html)).

Si quieres encontrar el dato de la consulta en sí,  tienes que invocar un método de lectura, que para este caso podría ser [**`fetchone()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html).

Por ejemplo:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql="SELECT MAX(id) FROM columna"
cursor.execute(sql)
maxid = cursor.fetchone()
print(maxid)
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, con tu solución me devuelve el maxid como un array con su segundo valor vació, pero solo tengo que escribir maxid[0] y me devuelve solo el id, sin comas ni comillas.